# Recursive HTML Elements using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create a Comment system which can have comments on comments. To do so I need to write the following HTML

```
<div ng-show="article.fetchedComments" ng-init="article.fetchedComments=[]" class="commentsContainer">
  <div ng-repeat="comment in article.fetchedComments" ng-show="article.fetchedComments" id="{{comment._id}}" class="eachcomment">
    <div class="col-md-2"><img ng-src="img/profilePicture/{{comment.user.id}}.jpg" width="50" class="profilepicture"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"><span ng-show="comment.user.id === userid" ng-click="deleteComment(comment._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove right"></span>
      <h5 class="commentusername"><a href="/user/{{comment.user.id}}">{{comment.user.name}}</a></h5>
      <p>{{comment.content}}</p><span ng-show="comment.user.id === userid" class="editreply"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to implement the reply section. On clicking the reply button it should fetch the comments for that comment and list them. For 1 level I could just use the same HTML and paste it after the `Reply` is clicked. But for a tree like structure, what should I do? If you do not understand what I need to do, I want to implement a comment system like Quora.

Answer (score 0):

Create an obj that contains your tree structure and your comments. Then you can flatten this object down recursivley to an array of comment node objects and save the shifting (right) inside an attribute for each node.

With this you can use `ng-repeat` to list all of the comments. Just shift them to the right depending on the calculated (shifting) attribute.

If you want to add a new comment you need to search for the parent node recursivley in your tree structure (important: save an id to refind this node!) and add a new comment object to the *child-comments* array.